# Get minimum and maximum value using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list that has values as displayed below
Using Linq how can i get the minimum from COL1 and maximum from COL2 for the selected id.

```
id     COL1      COL2
=====================
221     2         14
221     4         56   
221    24         16   
221     1         34
222    20         14    
222     1         12 
222     5         34
```

Based on the below list it should display id `221 1 56` and `222 1 34`
help me out

Comment: Do you want min and max value for each ID ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you want Min and Max value for each ID in the list, then you have to group by `ID` and the get MAX and Min accordingly like:

```
var query = yourList.GroupBy(r=> r.ID)
                    .Select (grp => new 
                              {
                                ID = grp.Key, 
                                Min = grp.Min(t=> t.Col1), 
                                Max = grp.Max(t=> t.Col2)
                              });
```

Use [Enumerable.Max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max.aspx) method to calculate maximum like:

```
var max = yourList.Max(r=> r.Col1);
```

Use [Enumerable.Min](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.min.aspx) method to calculate minimum on a field like:

```
var min = yourList.Min(r=> r.Col2);
```

Comment: OP mentions `for the selected id`, so you should probably use `Where` to filter.

Comment: @VimalStan, yes, read the question again and modified the answer

Comment: Use  }); instead of }: in the end of query.

Answer (score 3):

You can sort, something like:

```
var min = yourList.OrderBy(p => p.Col1).First();
var max = yourList.OrderByDescending(p => p.Col1).First();
```

Comment: I think that sorting cost O(n x log(n)) and finding the max value only costs O(n).
So sorting just for finding the min, max is not good answer.

Comment: Sorting performance is negligible when a query doesn't have to run every second. This answer is quite efficient over Habib's.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid making two calls to the database, there is another way to perform it:

```
var result = query.GroupBy(r => 0)
    .Select (grp => new 
    {
        Min = grp.Min(t => t.Col1), 
        Max = grp.Max(t => t.Col2)
    });
```

This will perform just one execution in the database, and it will return both results.