# Select Min and Max LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity

```
select description, min(date), max(date), sum(value1), sum(value2) from table
where description = 'Axxx' and filter = 'L'
group by description
```

How to perform this query using Linq / C#?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yes, I just can not filter the min and max date.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not tested, but the following should work:

```
table
   .Where(x=>x.description=="Axxx" && x.filter=="L")
   .GroupBy(x=>x.description)
   .Select(x=>new {
       description=x.Key,
       mindate=x.Min(z=>z.date),
       maxdate=x.Max(z=>z.date),
       sumvalue1=x.Sum(z=>z.value1),
       sumvalue2=x.Sum(z=>z.value2)
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work. not tested

```
 var q = from b in table
            group b by b.Owner into g
            where description = 'Axxx'
            select new
                       {
                           description = g.description ,
                           date = g.min(),
                           date = g.max(),
                           value1= g.Sum(item => item.value1),
                           value2= g.Sum(item => item.value2),
                       };
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work

```
var q = from s in db.table
            where description = 'Axxx' and filter = 'L'
            group s by s.description into g
            select new {YourDescription = g.description, MaxDate = g.Max(s => s.date) }
```

That answer may help, too .. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16684769/get-minimum-and-maximum-value-using-linq)