# Convert and get maximum

Tags: c#, linq

I have an list of object which is have string "Value1" property and it is actually double.

So, I just want to get maximum and minimum values from my list with converting the property double.

That is my class.

```
public class Function
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

I have a `List<Function>` and I need to get minimum "value1". Btw I am pretty sure about value1 can convertible to double. Is it possible to do this action in one line ?

Comment: dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16684769/get-minimum-and-maximum-value-using-linq

Comment: @Thennarasan this is not a duplicate of what you posted. Issue here is type conversion, issue you posted relates to linq and grouping.

Comment: Are you talking about a custom object or literally the type `object` as in `List<object>`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get minimum and maximum value using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16684769/get-minimum-and-maximum-value-using-linq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about simple casting?

```
myList.Max(x => double.Parse(x.Value1));
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but `x` is of type `object` and object has no property `Value1`. This will not compile

Comment: yes, sorry, I'm an idiot, I have fixed the answer to use `double.Parse` now. It assumes all Value1s are parseable into double, though.

Comment: This will not change the compile time error, if x is of type `object`. I've asked the OP for clarification

Comment: You are right. I've assumed OP meant a custom object.

Comment: @netchkin I could not see a tiny point in my function. This answer helped me. Thank you...

Comment: @Basin not at the time I asked that question

Answer (score 1):

if you indeed want the min and the max, and you are sure the strings are all doubles:

```
string[] values = new[] { "1.1", "1.5", "2.654987" };

var doubles = values.Select(Convert.ToDouble);

var min = doubles.Min();
var max = doubles.Max();
```

Comment: It could not fit to my needs thats why I modified my question.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ can make it look nice

```
var sum = list.Select(item => item.Value1).Select(double.Parse).Sum();
```

You can pass a `double.Parse` function as parameter to the `Select`.
Notice that `double.Parse` will throw exception if `Value1` is not valid `double`

Answer (score 0):

It does matter whether you run your statement against database or not. if you do so and you do in one connection, so you will need to make all values in the same length as 'string' via a 'Select' statement and 'SqlFunctions.Replicate', and then 'Max' is going to work; but if your value contains decimals you will have trouble. Another way to escape from this solution is to fetch all value into memory using 'ToList' for instance; after that cast 'string' value to 'double' to get 'Max' statement working. but the downside is that all values is fetched into memory once